# How does the inverse transform sampling work when the CDF is not known?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

I am trying to understand the use of the inverse transform sampling and I saw the following definition:

Let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution can be described by the cumulative distribution function $F_X$.
We want to generate values of $X$ which are distributed according to this distribution.

1. Generate a random number $u$ from the standard uniform distribution in the interval $[0, 1]$.
2. Find the inverse of the desired CDF, e.g. ${\displaystyle F_{X}^{-1}(x)}$.
3. Compute $X = F_X^{-1}(x)$. The computed random variable ${\displaystyle X}$ has distribution ${\displaystyle F_{X}(x)}$.

Now, I get the situations where $F_x$ is known (for example the normal distribution or some other) but how can I compute the third point in the definition above when I only have a sample of a certain random variable, e.g. the returns of a stock? How can I go from this sample of stock returns and use the inverse transform sampling? (I do not want to assume normal distribution for the returns).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: If $F_X$ is not known and you still want to make use of it in some way then I think you can at most generate an approximating CDF $F$ on base of the sample $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$. An example for that is: $$F(x):=\frac{|\{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\mid X_i\leq x\}|}{n}$$

Comment: The answer is straightforward: you must estimate $F_X$ somehow -- there's a world of possible approaches to that -- and then you can simulate data based on that estimate.  Any conceivable procedure that answers this question will be equivalent to this approach.